# MYSQL get diffrence between two dattimes in minutes and update in field

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have table with 3 fileds `id`, `startdate`, `enddate`. Now I have added new field called `mins` as mentioned in image.

I need query to get diffrence between `startdate` and `enddate` in minutes and store in fields mysql.

[image]

Comment: Please look here for answer on the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40409810/6756033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php) :

```
UPDATE YourTable t 
set t.mins =  ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.startdate,t.enddate)) ;
```

Comment: when differences not proper it stores value in minus

Comment: @MasterDev Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have added the minutes column later, you should update your table using the following query.

```
 INSERT INTO yourTable 
    SELECT 
      inn.id,
      inn.StartDate,
      inn.EndDate,
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        MINUTE,
        inn.StartDate,
        inn.EndDate
      ) AS diff 
    FROM
      `yourTable` inn 
      ON DUPLICATE KEY 
      UPDATE 
        id = inn.id,
        `StartDate` = inn.StartDate,
        EndDate = inn.EndDate,
        Mins = TIMESTAMPDIFF(
          MINUTE,
          inn.StartDate,
          inn.EndDate
        ) ;
```

Suppose this is the initial state of your table

```
  id  StartDate            EndDate                Mins  
------  -------------------  -------------------  --------
     1  2016-11-07 12:53:27  2016-11-30 12:53:35         0
     2  2016-11-02 12:53:41  2016-12-07 12:53:45         0
     3  2016-11-16 12:53:52  2017-02-16 12:53:56         0
```

Executing the above query transforms the table like this :

```
    id  StartDate            EndDate                Mins  
------  -------------------  -------------------  --------
     1  2016-11-07 12:53:27  2016-11-30 12:53:35     33120
     2  2016-11-02 12:53:41  2016-12-07 12:53:45     50400
     3  2016-11-16 12:53:52  2017-02-16 12:53:56    132480
```